# Join three tables and subtract sum of column from a column data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables **accounts**, **receivables** and **receiveds .**

My basic table is **receivables** I want to get the names from the **account** table and then subtract the sum of received column in **receiveds** table form the receivable column in **receivables** table with same ref numbers. i want to ignore if the balance is zero.

accounts

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | John |
| 23 | Kahn |
| 24 | Falis |
| 25 | Haseni |
| 26 | Gent |

receivables

| id | receivable | Ref |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 70 | A1 |
| 24 | 100 | A2 |
| 26 | 60 | A3 |
| 24 | 15 | A4 |

receiveds

| ref | id | received |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 22 | 30 |
| A2 | 24 | 60 |
| A1 | 22 | 40 |
| A3 | 26 | 20 |
| A2 | 24 | 10 |

desired results

| id | name | ref | receivable | received | balance | total_id_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | Falis | A2 | 100 | 70 | 30 | 45 |
| 26 | Gent | A3 | 60 | 20 | 40 | 40 |
| 24 | Falis | A4 | 15 | 0 | 15 | 45 |

I have tried this code but it's not working for me

```
SELECT * 
FROM receivables AS rvb 
  LEFT JOIN accounts AS acc 
    ON rvb.id = acc.id 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(received) as sum_rvd FROM receiveds) AS rvd 
    ON acc.id = rvd.id where rvb.receivable>rvd.sum_rvd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INNER JOIN`s filter out NULL values and the `HAVING` clause removes zero-balance rows.

```sql
SELECT 
    accounts.* ,
    ra.receivable,
    rd.received,
    ra.receivable - rd.received as balance
FROM accounts
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT id, SUM(receivable) as receivable FROM receivables GROUP BY id ) ra 
        ON ra.id = accounts.id
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT id, SUM(received) as received FROM receiveds GROUP BY id ) rd 
        ON rd.id = accounts.id
HAVING balance > 0
```

UPDATE

With a `ref` field we just need to add it as another grouping field for subselects, and change second `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` (actually looks like it was a mistake from the start, coz we missed entries without `receiveds` that still had positive balance). Also changing `received` field to a `COALESCE` to get zeroes instead of NULL's (indicating non existing rows in a `receiveds` table).
Since you need an overall per-id `total_id_balance` field, the natural way to grab it - is using [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html). Note, they are supported only for MySQL 8.0+.
So the resulting query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    accounts.* ,
    ra.ref,
    ra.receivable,
    COALESCE(rd.received, 0) as received,
    ra.receivable - COALESCE(rd.received, 0) as balance,
    SUM( ra.receivable - COALESCE(rd.received, 0) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) as total_id_balance
FROM accounts
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT id, SUM(receivable) as receivable, ref FROM receivables GROUP BY id, ref ) ra 
        ON ra.id = accounts.id
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id, SUM(received) as received, ref FROM receiveds GROUP BY id, ref ) rd 
        ON 
            rd.id = accounts.id 
            AND 
            ra.ref = rd.ref
HAVING balance > 0
ORDER BY ref
```

Comment: Thanks for your support bro. i tried this bit it's not working for me

Comment: What does it give?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\test.php:32 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\test.php(32): mysqli_num_rows(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\test.php on line 32

Comment: Try running the query via mysql console, or some DB management tool like phpMyAdmin

Comment: Glad it helped. Mind accepting the answer?

Comment: sorry I am new to the forum. I accepted the answer.
I also wanted if possible to add a column named "REF" in both receivable and receiveds tables and allow to subtract the only if there two column data match

Comment: Looks like u've accepted another answer actually. About a `ref` column, please update your answer with new circumstances. And I (or some one else) will update the answer.

Comment: Do you mean I should post another thread?

Comment: I don't think you should. Add new input data, tables schemes and desired result to this one.

Comment: i have edited @jared

Comment: thanks bro. it's working very well.... can I select all columns from receivable. I wanted to add some other columns in receivables but not affecting the calculations to appear in my desired data columns
I thank you again for you time and support

Comment: I got it bro. how can I mark this thread **SOLVED** ?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me -

EDIT-
Add support for non-unique id in `receivables`

```
SELECT acc.id ,acc.name, res.receivable, res.received, (res.receivable - res.received) AS balance
FROM accounts AS acc JOIN 
    (SELECT recv.id, recv.receivable, rec.received 
     FROM (
         SELECT id, SUM(receivable) AS receivable
         FROM receivables
         GROUP BY id) AS recv JOIN 
            (SELECT id, SUM(received) AS received 
             FROM receiveds 
             GROUP BY id) AS rec ON rec.id = recv.id 
         WHERE rec.received < recv.receivable) AS res ON res.id = acc.id;
```

Comment: Nope, this is not working. At least not when `receivables.id` is not uniq. For test, add two `receivables` for id 25 with values of 20 each (40 in summ). Add a single `received` for id 25 with a value of 30. Expected balance is 10. No output for id 25 with this query.

Comment: Just in case that receivables.id is not a primary key, from the example I thought that is a primary key. I will edit it in my approach that will support duplicate ids in receivables. Thanks for the note!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is possible to have an id in receivables without a corresponding id in receiveds, the second join needs to be a LEFT JOIN and you need to handle the NULLs in your SELECT list -

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    ra.receivable,
    IFNULL(rd.received, 0) received,
    ra.receivable - IFNULL(rd.received, 0) balance
FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, SUM(receivable) receivable
    FROM receivables
    GROUP BY id
) ra 
    ON a.id = ra.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, SUM(received) received
    FROM receiveds
    GROUP BY id
) rd 
    ON a.id = rd.id
HAVING balance > 0;
```

You can (and should) go a step further and remove the first derived table as it is unnecessary overhead -

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    SUM(ra.receivable) receivable,
    IFNULL(SUM(rd.received), 0) received,
    SUM(ra.receivable) - IFNULL(rd.received, 0) balance
FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN receivables ra
    ON a.id = ra.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, SUM(received) received
    FROM receiveds
    GROUP BY id
) rd
    ON a.id = rd.id
GROUP BY id
HAVING balance > 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ng_0PXOo)